# how to get checkbox with '-' minus symbol inside check box using css only?

Tags: html, css

get a minus "-" symbol inside checkbox using `html` and `css` only

I tried using

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].indeterminate = true;
```

but requirement is using `html` and `css` only

Comment: please add your code here :)

Comment: You can use the after pseudo class and absolute position it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css, that seem to have many solutions to your question.

Comment: do you mean "-" for the replacement of check mark? please show your code as well

Comment: use can use input indeterminate  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_indeterminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `label` posing like a `checkbox`, with a minus symbol inside. Like this:

```css
input {
  display: none
}

label {
  padding: 0 6px;
  border: 1px solid #eee
}

input:checked+label {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box">
  <label for="box">-</label>
</div>
```

Comment: your right @Paulie_D, now i've edited

Comment: please mark as complete if your satisfied @RohithSai